# Regex find word in the string

Tags: regex

In general terms I want to find in the string some substring but only if it is contained there.

I had expression :

```
^.*(\bpass\b)?.*$
```

And test string:

```
high pass h3
```

When I test the string via expression I see that whole string is found (but group "pass" not):

```
match : true
groups count : 1  
group : high pass h3
```

But that I needed, is that match has 2 groups : 
1: high pass h3 
2: pass

And when I test, for example, the string - high h3, I still had 1 group found - high h3

How can I do this?

Comment: 1. What platform (not all regex implementations are the same): Perl, Python, Java, .NET, ...? 2. "only if it is contained there" is not clear.

Comment: Why do you want the whole string as a match?

Comment: It could be multi line, getting him the complete lines including the word to be found.

Comment: Why I needed is because this is the only part of my regex expression and there is another patterns for seacrh which should work even if the "pass" not found.

Answer (score 98):

Use this one:

```
^(.*?(\bpass\b)[^$]*)$
```

1. First capture for the entire line.
2. Second capture for the expected word.

Check the [demo](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=42dd45eb).

More explanation:

```
          ┌ first capture
          |
 ⧽------------------⧼
^(.*?(\bpass\b)[^$]*)$
  ⧽-⧼          ⧽---⧼
   | ⧽--------⧼  |
   |     |       └ all characters who are not the end of the string
   |     |
   |     └ second capture
   |
   └ optional begin characters
```

Comment: Thansks! But problem is what I needed that the match (whole text) would be found even if "pass" isn't in the tested string, please see your demo. Is it possible?

Comment: Check this one: http://www.myregextester.com/?r=aa94f52d  `^(.*?(\bpass\b)[^$]*|[^$]*)$`

Comment: How to deal with case sensitive problem?

Answer (score 7):

You're just missing a bit for it to work (plus that `?` is at the wrong position).

If you want to match the frist occurance: `^(.*?)(\bpass\b)(.*)$`.
If you want to match the last occurance: `^(.*)(\bpass\b)(.*?)$`.

This will result in 3 capture groups: Everything before, the exact match and everything following.

`.` will match (depending on your settings almost) anything, but only a single character.
`?` will make the preceding element optional, i.e. appearing not at all or exactly once.
`*` will match the preceding element multiple times, i.e. not at all or an unlimited amount of times. This will match as many characters as possible.
If you combine both to `*?` you'll get a ungreedy match, essentially matching as few characters as possible (down to 0).

Edit:
As I read you only want `pass` and the complete string, depending on your implementation/language, the following should be enough: `^.*(\bpass\b).*?$` (again, the ungreedy match might be swapped with the greedy one). You'll get the whole expression/match as group 0 and the first defined match as group 1.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work in C# regex, string - "high h3", mathces not found at all, but I expected that if the string not found match should return whole string as a match result. Why I needed is because this is the only part of my regex expression and there is another patterns for seacrh which should work even if the "pass" not found.

Comment: Ah? "pass" should be optional? Did you think about defining alternative sequences using `|`? E.g. something like `^.*?(\b(?:passed|failed)\b).*?$` will match both alternatives. Why do you even have to match the whole line, considering it's what you might pass? You can make any sequence optional by adding `?`, but this might have an unexpected result when using wild card matches that could include your "keywords".

Answer (score 5):

A period only matches a single character, so you're

```
^.(\bpass\b)?.$
```

is matching:

- Start of input
- A single character
- Optionally

  - Word boundary
  - "pass"
  - Word boundary
- Single char
- End of input

which I would not expect to match "high pass h3" at all.

The regular expression:

```
pass
```

(no metacharacters) will match any string containing "pass" (but then so would a "find string in string" function, and this would probably be quicker without the complexities of a regex).