# Apache Exact Match Word Inside String

Tags: regex, apache

I am very close to solving this thanks to this post [Regex find word in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348326/regex-find-word-in-the-string)

But I am still not 100% there.

If I use this regex along with Apache's **BrowserMatchNoCase**

```
^(.*?)(\b360Spider\b)(.*)$
```

I get the following results:

- 360Spider = match
- 360spider = match
- 360SpIdEr = match
- 360spiders = no match
- Not360Spider = no match
- Not-360Spider = match
- Not-360spider = match

I need it to match the word 360Spider regardless of what is put in front or after the word, so NOT360Spider should be a match.

Thanks in advance, my regex has improved somewhat over the years but I am still nowhere close to fully understanding getting things perfect without leading to false positives.

At the same time I do not want to introduce other false positives which is why I am delving into this in the first place so other user-agent names likes "Exabot" and "Alexabot" I don't want the "exabot" part of Alexabot to be detected.

So let's say in another example:

```
^(.*?)(\bExabot\b)(.*)$
```

I get the following results:

- Alexabot = no match
- Exabot = match
- exAbot = match

If I remove word boundaries "\b" as follows:

```
^(.*?)(Exabot)(.*)$
```

I get the following results:

- Alexabot = match
- Exabot = match
- exAbot = match
- anythingExabot = match

So I guess I have to stick with the word boundaries "\b" now the trick is to get printf to write the "\b" into my string and not see it as a backspace character.

Comment: Remove word boundaries `\b`. It will also match `360spiders`, by the way.

Comment: *Is this even possible?* - No, it is not possible to understand what you are asking. It is surely not possible to match `exabot` with `^(.*?)(\b360Spider\b)(.*)$`.

Comment: Thanks guys I updated my question with a few more examples, seems I have to stick with `\b` word boundaries

Comment: To define a literal ``\`` in a regular string literal it is usually required to put double backslash. It is not necessary if you define a pattern in some text file that is read in and then parsed by an engine.

Comment: Thanks I figured out my printf syntax in my bash script `printf "BrowserMatchNoCase \"^(.*?)(\\\b${line}\\\b)(.*)$\" good_bot\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that once you add word boundaries around `360Spider` you can't match it inside another word, enclosed with digits or even `_` symbols that are also considered word chars.

If you need to match the word anywhere inside a string, you need to remove word boundaries, `\b`. However, *judging by your examples*, you still need the word boundaries as otherwise, you will match `exabot` in `Alexabot`.

Here is a way to define your pattern in Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
line='var_here'
printf "BrowserMatchNoCase \"^(.*?)(\\\b${line}\\\b)(.*)\$\" good_bot\n"
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/RyiBDm). Note it is a good idea to escape the `$` inside an interpolated string literal.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I can see why escaping that last $ in the printf string is important. Indeed I am stuck with word boundaries, without them there's just a whole world of false positives. This new regex is working 100% now. Strange though that `-` is ignored by the word boundary.

Comment: @MitchellK: You are welcome. If you need to tweak the word boundaries, feel free to drop a line. `-` is not ignored by a word boundary, the word boundary exists between `a` and `-`, between `-` and `a`, but not between `;` and `-`.

Comment: Thanks again Wiktor, you're a star. I will update my original question to become more of a question & answer.