# Java - Check if any of the words is contained in the text

Tags: java, string-matching

I was trying to implement a method which checks whether a list of words is contained in a text. The problem is I cannot use the contains method because I just want the word to be detected (if the word is 'car' then with the string 'cars' the method should return false). In addition, the method should be case-sensitive.

EDIT:

```
String goodWord="word";
String review="This is a text containing the word.";
System.out.println(review.matches("\\w*"+goodWord+"\\w*"));
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code examples. Also what is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think you can do it we regex. Check if the word is surrounded by spaces, dots, coma,... Or if it is in the start or the end of your text.

Comment: I've already tried with regex, but I am not sure of how to consider both the cases when the word is the starting one (no space before), or in the middle of the sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] goodWords = { "good", "word" };
        String goodWordsUnionPatternStr = "(" + String.join("|", goodWords) + ")";
        Pattern strContainsGoodWordsPattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\b" + goodWordsUnionPatternStr + "\\b.*");
        String review = "This is a text containing the word.";
        System.out.println(strContainsGoodWordsPattern.matcher(review).matches());
    }
}
```

Explained:

- `\b` is word boundary
- Pattern.compile is preferred way due to performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp to find words in text.

You should check this answer :
[Regex find word in the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348326/regex-find-word-in-the-string)

And you can try regex online with : https://regex101.com/

Comment: I edited the question, but it is not working still, the output of the code I posted is false.